# Web scraping span using rvest

Tags: html, web-scraping, nodes, rvest

I would like to extract a text contained in the website https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/918160/000091816018000065/form10-k2017.htm . I am looking Opinion on the Financial Statements headline and i have to extract only 1 paragraph which contains this word 'accompanying consolidated'. If there is a match then it should return all the text which starting with 'We have audited the.....' . I wanted to output this into a text file. I have tried different options and not able to find the right code to get this text . Can somebody please help me on this problem ?

Following code I have used to extract the information . But I am getting empty string.

```
library(rvest)

sample_url="https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/918160/000091816018000065/form10-k2017.htm"

cont<- read_html(sample_url)

output= gsub('\r\n',' ',html_nodes(cont_sree,'p') %>% html_text())

text=output[grepl("accompanying consolidated",output)]
```

Comment: ```I have tried different options and not able to find the right code to get this text``` .. then show us what you tried

Comment: the actual data is in https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/918160/000091816018000065/form10-k2017.htm , if you  run ```curl -s 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/918160/000091816018000065/form10-k2017.htm' --compressed | grep -i 'accompanying consolidated' | wc -l``` you get 1.

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik , Thank you for looking into this problem. I have edited my question and added the R code which I used for this problem . Can you please explain in which platform I can execute your 'curl' command .

Comment: MacOS ships with curl (since 2003 OSX 10.3 Jaguar release), all you need is a terminal. most linux systems ship with curl by default. in Windows, you can get curl and grep and wc from Cygwin, https://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh the page and use the network tab you will see the alternate source for the content you are interested in. You will note it returns XBRL Document. I would perhaps consider using xpath, rather than regex, to match on the `span` containing that text and grab the parent `div`; as that is really the representation on the page. Then, when extract text, check if `NA`.

---

**R:**

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

node_text <- read_html('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/918160/000091816018000065/form10-k2017.htm')%>%
     html_node(xpath="//span[contains(text(), 'accompanying consolidated')]/parent::div")%>%
     html_text()
result <- ifelse(is.na(node_text),'not found',node_text)
result
```

---

**Py (bs4 4.7.1 +)**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/918160/000091816018000065/form10-k2017.htm')
soup = bs(r.content,'lxml')
target = soup.select_one('div:has(span:contains("accompanying consolidated"))')
if target is None:
    print('Not found')
else:
    print(target.text)
```

Both were tested before answering.

For example (R):

[image]

py:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. I have just started using Stack overflow and not much familiar to post questions and codes in a proper way. Thanks for correcting that too.

Comment: Any other questions please ask.

Comment: I have tried this code and it returns nothing in both Python and R. But I would expect the output to be something "We have audited the accompanying consolidated balance sheets of AK Steel Holding Corporation ------" . The entire paragraph is which I am looking for .

Comment: I always test my code unless otherwise stated. Both run fine for me. How are you running these? Any error messages? Please see screen grabs edit.

Comment: I have tested the code again and this time R code works fine for me . I was tried in Office network earlier. That could be the reason for NA is my previous output. But python code still showing up some error . Python error is showing as  NotImplementedError: 'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.'). I would like to share the error part as screenshot. But not sure how to do that . I will reinstall these packages and will let you know the result . Since R code worked I have marked the tick mark . Thank you again for this help .

Comment: The python problem is because you need bs4 4.7.1 or higher. You want this as it there is considerably more functionality and some bugs have been fixed.

Comment: Since we both worked on similar domain (Analytics) I would like to connect with you in future If I have any troubles relates to VBA or Python or R. I am using SAS,R,Python , Excel VBA and MS SQL in most of my works. Could you please share your email or any way of preferable online communication so that I can connect with you in future. My email id is mvsreejith0@gmail.com.

Comment: Hi, you can post questions here and hopefully I will see them. For smaller questions you can find me in the room listed in my profile.

Comment: I have updated my beautifulsoup4 package (conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4) and now it's working fine.